# Conditionally format cells in an array based on values in a separate array

Tags: arrays, excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have array A (C5:G9) and array B (I5:M9). I want to conditionally format array A based on values in array B. If array B has the number 3 anywhere in its array, I want the corresponding cell in array A to be highlighted.

I've tried all kinds of if statements and I keep getting a circular reference error.

[Array Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKV6I.png)

Comment: `=AA1<>""` and apply to `A1:A10`? What do you mean by "If array B has any value anywhere in its array"?

Comment: I mean if array B has any value: text or number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve, if so then kindly follow the steps,

• First Select The `ARRAY A` i.e. from `C5:G9`,

• From `Home Tab` --> Goto `Conditional Formatting` (**Under Styles Group**),

• Click `New Rule` (**Short Cut is ALT H L N**),

• `New Formatting Rule` Box Opens,

• Now Select the **Rule Type** --> `Use A Formula To Determine Which Cells To Format`,

• In the `Edit the Rule Description` --> Format Values where this formula is true: , enter the below formula

```
=I5=3
```

• Click `Format` --> From `Fill Tab` --> Choose preferred `Background Color`,

• Press `Ok` --> `Ok` Done.

[image: ARRAY A CONDITIONALLY FORMATTED WHEN ARRAY B EQUALS 3]

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. It works! I was waaay overthinking this whole thing, and the solution is so much more simple than I imagined. You're awesome!